# How to untar a .tar.xz file

Tags: command-line, tar

I tried to run:

```
tar -zxvf name.tar.xz
```

but all I got was:

```
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: What do you call a normal install? A tar.xz is just a compressed archive of files.

Comment: I tried tar -zxvf name.tar.xz

Comment: Try replacing the z with J

Comment: 'gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
'

Comment: You may have an old os version that doesn't know about xz. Try decompressing first. xz -d blah.tar.xz then tar -xvf blah.tar

Comment: I hve the last ver of ubuntu... ill try to recompress

Comment: All you need to extract that is `tar xf /your/xz/file` to install it we need a link to the file, a name for the program and any install instruction you have used. Please edit your question.

Comment: What happens with `tar --xz -xvf  name.tar.xz`?

Answer (score 18):

The `z` flag of GNU tar (which is the version of `tar` shipped with Ubuntu) is used to speciy that the archive being processed is compressed using `gzip`, which is usually indicated by the `.tar.gz` (or, more rarely, `.tgz`) extension. In GNU tar, it is an error to use the `z` flag if the archive is not compressed with `gzip`, as you experience now.

Archives using the `.tar.xz` extension are compressed with xz, and the corresponding flag in GNU tar is `J`. Hence, replacing `z` with `J` in your command should solve your problem. In addition, you may get a "command not found" error if the xz tools are not installed on your system, which can be remedied by installing the `xz-utils` package.

Alternatively, you can simply omit the filetype-related flag altogether, and simply use `-xvf`; in that case `tar` will attempt to autodetect the compression format by analyzing the file. (You can probably also dispense with the `v` flag; it just prints a list of the extracted files, which is not usually useful.)

Comment: Alternatively, use the `a` flag to automatically determine the appropriate (de-)compressor from the archive file name.

Comment: @DavidFoerster No, the `a` flag is only used when creating archives. When extracting, it is sufficient to just not use any filetype-related flag at all.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that, but I just tried it.

Answer (score 4):

`.xz` is "A compression format using LZMA2 to yield very high compression ratios" and should be extracted with `ar` (`ar` is installed by default as part of GNU utils).

> The GNU `ar` program creates, modifies, and extracts from archives. An archive is a single file holding a collection of other files in a structure that makes it possible to retrieve the original individual files (called members of the archive).

There are more tools (like `tar`) but whatever other tool you use: make sure that that tool supports this ->

> The original files' contents, mode (permissions), timestamp, owner, and group are preserved in the archive, and can be restored on extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a 'tar.xz', so I used `unxz myfile.tar.xz` to uncompress the file, so I got the archive file `myfile.tar`. Then using the regular `tar` command  on an archive file, I could extract the contents `tar xvf myfile.tar`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command below to untar .tar.xz files.

Syntax:

```
tar -xJvf File_Name.tar.xz
```

Example:

```
tar -xJvf etc.tar.xz
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the most upvoted answer but with less information.

Comment: @pLumo I’d keep this answer as it provides a TL;DR, copy-pasteable solution. I couldn’t find any answer on this page to which this would be an “exact duplicate”.